# Using CSS transforms on bxSlider items break animation in Safari

Tags: safari, css-transforms, bxslider, translate3d

I came across this issue when upgrading to the latest version of bxSlider (v4.1). The new version is responsive and therefore uses `transform` to go between slides, rather than the old way of using the `left` property (used in v3.x).

I have created a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/SXZjV/

When viewed in Safari 5, the hover on the blocks don't do anything. However, when disabling `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);` via the inspector, the animations work fine.

**Is there a way to get the two transforms to work in harmony?**

Many thanks.

P.s. I am yet to test this behaviour in Safari 6 as I am currently running Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2):

The same to me in Safari 5.1.9. Only way I managed CSS animations to work is **using** included **"jQuery easing"**:

```
 $('#bxslider').bxSlider({
      useCSS: false,
      easing: 'easeInBack' //Or other animation http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ 
  });
```

P.S.
By the way it works on Safari 6 (Mountain Lion)